# Find the highest number using another function

Tags: c

could everyone please help me what is wrong with my code or what is missing from my code...
We have this activity where we have to find the highest number using another function..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf
int high (int n1);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, num[10];
  p("Input 10 numbers\n");
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
    p("Enter Number: ");
    s("%d",&num[i]);
   }
  p("Highest Number: %d",high(num[i]));
  getch();
}

int high (int n1)
{
 int l;
 for (l=0; l<n1; l++)
 {
  if (n1 > l)
  return n1;
 }
}
```

When I input any number I always got 37..

Comment: Why would this work?  You need to pass the array to the function and have the function return the largest element.  Here is a tutorial you can use: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/206002-finding-min-and-max-numbers-in-an-array/

Comment: This is tagged `C++` not `C`. If this is indeed `C++` you should consider using `<iostream>` instead of `<stdio.h>` and `std::vector<int>` instead of `int[]`

Answer (score 1):

`int high (int n1);` should be

```
int high (int *arr, int sz);  /* You need to pass an array */
```

`p("Highest Number: %d",high(num[i]));` should be

```
p("Highest Number: %d",high(num, 10));  /* Passing array now, not one element */
```

`int high()` should be re-written as:

```
int high (int *arr, int sz)
{
 int l, mx = INT_MIN;
 for (l=0; l<sz; l++)
 {
  if (mx < arr[l])
  {
    /* Left as an excercise */
  }
 }
 return mx;
}
```

---

As this is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I would suggest using [available C++ to find max in a range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element):

```
const int max = *std::max_element(&num[0], &num[10]); // #include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if you still need an answer, but I corrected your code. Here are the mistakes I found

```
int high (int n1)
{
 int l;
 for (l=0; l<n1; l++)
 {
  if (n1 > l)
  return n1;
 }
}
```

In this for-loop, there is the condition `l<n1` and inside the for loop you have the statement `if(n1 > l)` which will never be attained because of `l<n1`. You said you were getting 37 each time, but I was getting 10 instead. This shows it was undefined behavior because no real value was returned. ( This code part really didn't mean any sense either as this function doesn't even try to find the largest number ).

Another issue I found is you have used `getch()` without including `<conio.h>` ( Also pointing out that `<conio.h>` is not standard in C++ )

Well, even though this question is tagged C++, since the code is completely c, I have made a fixed code in c. I've removed `getch()` in the code. So here is the code

```
#include<limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf
int high (int *n1,int lar);       // now I have used *n1 to get the address of the array.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, num[10],lar=INT_MIN;   // the variable lar is given the minimum value that can be held by an int
  p("Input 10 numbers\n");
  for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
    p("Enter Number: ");
    s("%d",&num[i]);
   }
  p("Highest Number: %d",high(num,lar));  // sending the entire array to the function by sending its address

}
int high (int *n1,int lar)
{
 int l;
 for (l=0; l<10; l++)  // since the size you have taken for your array is 10, I have used 10 here. But if you don't know the size beforehand, pass the size as an argument to the function
 {
  if (n1[l] >lar )    // Well, this is the simple part
   lar=n1[l];         // Simply assigning the largest value to lar
 }
 return lar;          // Finally returning the value lar.
}
```

Well, hope this helps you.

Comment: I gotta admit that it was my mistake to tag c++... I know for sure that it was definitely c.. well anyways Thanks again for your help..